# Why not implement a time controlled task in the current thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, time, concurrency

When implementing a function to work on a task in a specific time range (for example, monitor a value every 1 minute and 10 mins time limit in total), the popular solution is to use `Timer` or `ScheduledExecutorService` java util classes to schedule tasks on a separate thread.

Wondering why not just implement the timed task on the current thread instead of creating a new thread to handle that?

Comment: a new thread has its own place in the operating system timeschedule, and you have qa new task to run code, a exsting task can not run parallel the task and the monitoring

Comment: I think maybe I can do start time stop->monitor-> return-> sleep current thread-> monitor, quit monitor when condition met or time out?

Comment: You can do it in a run method which executes your task and then waits for 10 minutes, But if yout want exactly every 10 minutes, then you must calculate time processing task into those 10 minutes. Of course there is a problem, if task processing time exceeds 10 minutes You must use wait and not sleep which takes cpu much more

Comment: @lightrek you need to learn somewhat more about operating system. keeping the task alive costs more resources, than the timer. that will only run when the tzimespan is reached. but as this is simoe to imlement, you can chekc it

Comment: Do you mean "monitoring a value for 10 mins" (as written) or "monitoring a value every 10 mins"?  Those almost certainly have different solutions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Should be monitor a value every 1 minute and 10 mins time limit in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sleeping main thread freezes your app

The entire point to multi-threading is to offload work from the initial thread running your app.

A thread sleeping until a certain time is not doing any other work. If the main thread of your app is the one asleep, then your app is entirely suspended and useless. If the thread running your GUI is the one asleep, then your app appears to be frozen to the user, apparently crashed, and effectively useless.

Also, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281530/why-not-implement-a-time-controlled-task-in-the-current-thread/71281676#comment125997921_71281530), threads as currently implemented in Java are relatively expensive in terms of memory and CPU. So we generally avoid having more than a few/several/dozens of threads running at a time. In the future, if [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) succeeds with its [virtual threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8277131), this situation may change radically.

You commented:

> I think maybe I can do start time stop->monitor-> return-> sleep current thread-> monitor, quit monitor when condition met or time out?

That is effectively what a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) does. You define a task as a `Runnable` or `Callable`. The executor service runs your task periodically. In that task you can check for a condition on which you are waiting.

So no need for you to reinvent the wheel. Use the *Executors* framework built into Java; it’s excellent.

Search for that class name. Much has been already written on the subject, some of it authored by me. Search to learn more.

Regarding [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html), that class was supplanted years ago by the Executors framework. This fact is noted in the Javadoc.

## Task reschedules itself

You clarified that your goal is to check a condition every minute for a maximum of ten times.

One way to do this is to have the task reschedule itself.

```java
public class ConditionCheckingTask implements Runnable 
{
    private final ScheduledExecutorService ses ;
    private final Instant whenInstantiated = Instant.now() ;

    // Constructor
    public ConditionCheckingTask( final ScheduledExecutorService ses ) {
        this.ses = ses ;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if( someConditionIsTrue ) {
            doSomething ;
        } else if ( ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between( this.whenInstantiated , Instant.now() ) > 10 ) {
            // We have exceeded our time limit, so let this task die.
            return ;
        } else {  // Else wait a minute to check condition again.
            this.ses.schedule( this , 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that accessing `someConditionIsTrue` is thread-safe. For example, if some other thread is flipping a boolean flag to signal our task, make that flag an `AtomicBoolean`. To learn more, search Stack Overflow, and read the book listed below.

Somewhere in your app, instantiate and remember a `ScheduledExecutorService` object.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
```

Be sure to eventually shut down the executor service before your app exits. Search to learn more. This has been addressed many times on Stack Overflow.

Instantiate your task. Pass the scheduled executor service to the task’s constructor, so that it might reschedule itself every minute.

```
ConditionCheckingTask task = new ConditionCheckingTask( scheduledExecutorService ) ;
```

To start things off, schedule a run of that task with little or no delay.

```
scheduledExecutorService.schedule( task , 0 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ) ;
```

As part of the first run, the task will reschedule itself.

---

Note: Before deploying any multi-threaded code, be sure to study well the excellent book by Goetz et al., [*Java Concurrency In Practice*](https://jcip.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. But a question: task reschedule itself, then the task need 10 threads to run if we hit the time limit? Because I remember the ScheduledExecutorService.schedule can only be used for one thread.

Comment: @lightrek You can configure a scheduled executor service [with a single thread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()) or [with multiple threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool(int)). Your problem of a task rescheduling itself needs only a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

> Wondering why not just implement the timed task on the current thread
> instead of creating a new thread to handle that?

Your "current" thread is perhaps the one which is processing the main request ( e.g., http request or a task/job coordinator). Timed task on one of these would tie this thread up for any other work until the task completes. On http based services this can leads to http timeouts etc. which is not a good design both in-terms of end user experience and the computing resource usage.
And generally as a good practice you do not spawn another new thread for the task, you rather use a thread pool for efficient resource utilization.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in the current thread because your main program runs in a thread of it's own and you don't have much control over it. You can at most put it on sleep. So, you'll start your main program on one thread which will spin off another thread to run your task on schedule.