# Task schedule itself inside run() method will cause too many thread created?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281530/why-not-implement-a-time-controlled-task-in-the-current-thread/71281676#71281676):

```
public class ConditionCheckingTask implements Runnable 
{
    private final ScheduledExecutorService ses ;
    private final Instant whenInstantiated = Instant.now() ;

    // Constructor
    public ConditionCheckingTask( final ScheduledExecutorService ses ) {
        this.ses = ses ;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if( someConditionIsTrue ) {
            doSomething ;
        } else if ( ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between( this.whenInstantiated , Instant.now() ) > 100000 ) {
            // We have exceeded our time limit, so let this task die.
            return ;
        } else {  // Else wait a minute to check condition again.
            this.ses.schedule( this , 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

The task schedule itself inside run() method. Suppose the time limit is 100000,  then 100000 threads will be created? Since each schedule call will need a separate thread to run, right?

Answer (score 1):

> each schedule call will need a separate thread to run, right?

Probably not.

All we know from the code that you showed is that `ses` refers to a `ScheduledExecutorService`, and since that's only an interface, we don't actually know what it will do; but any practical implementation of that interface most likely will be some kind of [*thread pool*](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-pools.html).

A simple thread pool has a [*blocking queue*](https://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/blocking-queues.html) of tasks, and a small number of *worker threads* that each sit in a loop awaiting tasks and performing them;

```java
    while (true) {
        Runnable task = queue.take();
        task.run();
    }
```

In this way, the number of threads used can be much smaller than the number of tasks that are submitted to the queue.

A `ScheduledExecutorService` such as [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) works in pretty much the same way, except that the queue is some kind of [*priority queue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). A priority queue returns the tasks in the order in which they are scheduled to run instead of returning them in the same order as they were submitted. Each worker loops, waiting until a task at the head of the queue is due, and then it take()s the task, runs it, and goes back to await the next task, same as in the simple thread pool.

Comment: thanks, but in this case, there is no due of the tasks, all the tasks have to keep alive, for example, the run schedule itself for 100 times, then we have to use 100 sized queue for 100 active threads, right?

Comment: @lightrek The task in your example does _not_ "keep alive" in the case where it schedules a new task. In the only place where you showed a call to `ses.schedule(...)`, that's the last thing that your task `run()` method does before returning.